# Packer google cloud authentication within vpc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, firewall, google-oauth, packer

We are using Packer to build images in a GCP compute instance. Packer tries to grab the image based on project and image as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-name>/global/images/<image-name>?alt=json
```

Then it throws an error: 
`oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: dial tcp 108.177.111.84:443: i/o timeout`

Based on security principle, our compute instance has no external IP address, therefore it does not have access to internet. In this case, `accounts.google.com` is no longer accessible. Then how can we authenticate google apis?

I tried to enable firewall rules and provide routes for internet access. But based on the requirement stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#internet_access_reqs), the instance still won't have access if it does not have external IP address.

This means we must have a separate way to authenticate googleapis. 
But does Packer support this?

Here is the packer builder we have:

```
"builders": [
    {
        "type": "googlecompute",
        "project_id": "test",
        "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
        "source_image_family": "{{user `source_family`}}",
        "source_image": "{{user `source_image`}}",
        "source_image_project_id": "{{user `source_project_id`}}",
        "region": "{{user `region`}}",
        "zone": "{{user `zone`}}",
        "network": "{{user `network`}}",
        "subnetwork": "{{user `subnetwork`}}",
        "image_name": "test-{{timestamp}}",
        "disk_size": 10,
        "disk_type": "pd-ssd",
        "state_timeout": "5m",
        "ssh_username": "build",
        "ssh_timeout": "1000s",
        "ssh_private_key_file": "./gcp-instance-key.pem",
        "service_account_email": "test-account@test-mine.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "omit_external_ip": true,
        "use_internal_ip": true,
        "metadata": {
            "user": "build"
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you launching your packer script? CI/CD, manually?

Comment: We are setting it up. So manually for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want manually you will need to have an ssh tunnel open on a working compute instance inside the project or in a vpc that has a peering enabled on the network the compute you want to reach is.

If you then use a CI with a runner like gitlab-ci, be sure to create the runner inside the same vpc or in a vpc with a peering.

If you don't want to create a compute with an external ip you could try to open a vpn connection to the project and do it through the vpn.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific on this. We were actually running Packer inside vpc. The issue was that we don't have access to accounts.google.com. 
Although there exists private access to googleapis.com as per [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access) and we set it up already, but I don't see private access to accounts.google.com, which is used to authenticate googleapis.com, this is where the problem occurs.

Comment: haaaa you have authent issues, I missinterpreted as you spoke of external ip... Could you update your question with the service account roles?

Comment: Another stupid question did you try to use a NAT router?

Comment: Thanks. It's not stupid at all. We will think about this option using NAT.